# How to correctly run Remote Applications using RDS RemoteApps?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, rdp, windows-10-desktop

Im running a remote Desktop App on Windows 10 home. The RDP file is having the RemoteApplication mode for a particular application on Windows 10 pro. The Application runs well but i notice there are other applications running in the System tray on the client application. These applications are from the Remote Desktop where windows 10 pro is running

Any idea how to get rid of this ...